# Concatenate all combinations of elements in two separate arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

How would you take two arrays and concatenate the elements and return them in a new array? For instance here are two arrays:

```js
const whoArr = ["my", "your"];    
const credentialArr = ["name", "age", "gender"].
```

I would like to return a new array containing the elements:

```js
["my name", "my age", "my gender", "your name", "your age", "your gender"]
```

`.join` and `.concat` don't quite work.

Comment: Define “doesn’t quite work”.

Comment: .concat returns an array with all the elements in both arrays as one larger array.

Comment: .join returns the items in string

Comment: you can try that: whoArr.map(item => credentialArr.map(i => `${item} ${i}`).join(',') ).join(',').split(',');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested loops to loop over array 1, and for each iteration, you loop over array 2.

Here I use `forEach()` but you can use a normal `for` loop or a `for of` loop  too:

```js
const whoArr = ["my", "your"];
const credentialArr = ["name", "age", "gender"];

const output = [];
whoArr.forEach(who => {
  credentialArr.forEach(cred => {
    output.push(who + ' ' + cred)
  })
})

console.log(output)
```

Here's the same approach but using `for of` loops and template literals to make the string:

```js
const whoArr = ["my", "your"];
const credentialArr = ["name", "age", "gender"];

const output = [];
for (let who of whoArr) {
  for (let cred of credentialArr) {
    output.push(`${who} ${cred}`);
  }
}

console.log(output)
```